# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как объединить картинку и музыку?

Tags: python

У меня проблема, я хочу объединить музыку, текст и картинку. Но у меня сначала играет музыка, а потом уже картинка с текстом. Как их объединить? Я знаю, что для музыки надо составить отдельный поток, но я не знаю как.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
from playsound import playsound

root = Tk()

Image = Image.open("image_.jpg")
Image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image)

panel = Label(root, image = Image)
panel.pack()

T = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=32)
T.pack()
T.insert(tk.END,"Король и шут - Дурак и Молния...")

playsound("audio.mp3")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Замените изображение текстом, а заголовок формулировкой сути своего вопроса в виде вопросительного предложения, написанного не капсом. На оформленный подобным образом вопрос вряд ли кто-то захочет отвечать.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, спасибо что подсказали как изменить текст. Буду благодарен если вы оцените его ещё раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from threading import Thread

...

Thread(target=playsound, args=('"audio.mp3"',)).start()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!